# How increase height while scroll down but don't decrease when scroll up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm in a One Page project, and I need a DIV to increase the height while scrolling down, but when scrolling up, keep the height, and does not decrease.

I'm using JQuery with the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $broca = $('#corpo');
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        $broca.height( st - 600 );
        if( st == 0 ) {
            $broca.hide();
        } else {
            $broca.show();
        }
    }).scroll();
```

Answer (score 2):

To detect if the scrolling is going down, or up, you can always store the last value of the scroll, and then compare it to the `scrollTop()` at the event handler:

```
var lastVal = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastVal){
        // Is scrolling down... Increase height of div
    } else {
       // Is scrolling up, do nothing...
    }
    lastVal = st;
});
```

Comment: This answer is correct.  Add something like... `$("#corpo").css({height: "+=" + (st - lastVal) + "px"});` to the "Is scrolling down" section.